# Dictionary resources and Binding

Tags: c#, binding

I need access to borderbrush from code, how can bind?

This not work:

```
BorderBrush="{Binding color}"

<Border x:Name="brd"  Background="Black" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="3">
```

Here my xaml.

```
<UserControl x:Class="window6.Kbd"
         x:Name="teclado"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:fps="clr-namespace:FPS.VirtualKeyboard;assembly=FPS.VirtualKeyboard"
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="418"  Width="Auto" d:DesignHeight="177.326" Height="Auto" >
<Grid d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalMargin">
    <fps:VirtualKeyboard  x:Name="virtualKeyboard"    BorderBrush="{Binding Color1}"  >

        <fps:VirtualKeyboard.Resources>

            <fps:GetCharacterDependsOnSpecialKeysConverter x:Key="GetCharacterDependsOnSpecialKeysConverter"/>


            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type fps:RegularKey}">
                <Canvas>
                    <RepeatButton 

    Focusable="False"
    Content="{Binding .}"
    Canvas.Left="{Binding Left}"
    Canvas.Top="{Binding Top}"
    Width="{Binding Width}"
    Height="{Binding Height}"
    Command="fps:VirtualKeyboard.ClickCommand">
                        <RepeatButton.ContentTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource GetCharacterDependsOnSpecialKeysConverter}}">
                                        <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding .}"/>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                                    </ContentControl>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </RepeatButton.ContentTemplate>
                    </RepeatButton>
                </Canvas>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type fps:SpecialKey}">
                <Canvas>
                    <RepeatButton x:Name="btn"  Focusable="False" Content="{Binding .}" Canvas.Left="{Binding Left}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Top}" Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}"   Command="fps:VirtualKeyboard.ClickCommand">
                        <RepeatButton.ContentTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </RepeatButton.ContentTemplate>
                    </RepeatButton>
                </Canvas>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLocked}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"  Value="Yellow" TargetName="btn"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type fps:NumPadKey}">
                <Canvas>
                    <RepeatButton x:Name="btn" Focusable="False" Content="{Binding .}" Canvas.Left="{Binding Left}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Top}" Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}"   Command="fps:VirtualKeyboard.ClickCommand">
                        <RepeatButton.ContentTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding NumCase}" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </RepeatButton.ContentTemplate>
                    </RepeatButton>
                </Canvas>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLocked}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"  Value="Red" TargetName="btn"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>




            <Style  TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}"   >
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"   />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">

                            <Grid >

                                <Border x:Name="brd"  Background="Black" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="3">
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">

                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="brd" Value="Gray"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

        </fps:VirtualKeyboard.Resources>


    </fps:VirtualKeyboard>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please don't delete your question after you have figured it out. You should use comments for messages like this. Also, if the answer solved your problem, accept by clicking the tick mark. If you figured it out by yourself, post your own answer, for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
brd.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
```

If you need to bind to another property, then:

```
brd.SetBinding(Border.BorderBrushProperty, new Binding("SomeProperty") { Source = someObject });
```

[Edit] Attempt #3 :)

Not sure I understand completely, but this is probably what you are looking for:

```
BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
```

Now set `BorderBrush` of your `RepeatButton` and it should work.

Comment: @Arlistan - I think I finally got what you are looking for. Updated the answer.

Comment: Yes, if you do this change in the template, then set RepeatButton.BorderBrush to the brush that you need, and it will work.

Comment: @Arlistan - it is not clear what you do. You showed only template. It is not clear what VirtualKeyboard control is and how many repeat buttons is using. It can have more than repeat button. Ideally you should not access template elements from code at all. However, you can do that, but I can't suggest anything until I see the code.